# Will Route53 private hosted zone work over AWS VPC Peering

Tags: amazon-web-services

Consider the following scenario.

I have a bunch of appliances that serve my production environment (RDS, Mongo, Cache, Search etc...).

On the other side I have 2 more application environments (Lets say, **Legacy** and **NewGen**). Each has its own deployments, and resides in its own VPC.

I would like both my Legacy and NewGen to be able to "talk" with my appliances VPC. Thats what the VPC peering is for.

What I would also like to do is, with in the appliances VPC to create a **private hosted zone** that will map some **rds.comp.com** or **cache.comp.com** routes to their designated instances/services and be **able to make calls to rds.comp.com or cache.comp.com from my Legacy or NewGen VPCs**.

Before I get into this I would like to know if what i am asking is possible or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can achieve this using a Internal Loadbalancer in your VPC.

Comment: How does having a LoadBalancer help me with this?

Comment: So you have 3 VPC in your case VPC1: for legacy VPC2: for New Gen and VPC3: for Appliances and you want VPC1 and VPC2 to interact with VPC3 please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: correct. but i want fixed dns names between them. and there is no internet communication

Comment: Yes so Internal Loadbalancers are there for fixed DNS check this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-internal-load-balancers.html you point your Domains this this Internal ELB and can use those domains Privately without exposing to Public

Comment: Do i have to use ELB? or can i just create a DNS record like mentioned in the question?

Comment: DNS record will work too but work becomes more easy with ELB's :)

Comment: I would point out that it will work equally well with or without an ELB.  There is no ELB requirement for a Private Hosted Zone DNS. The need for an ELB would be based on your specific load and uptime requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your scenario is directly supported by [Amazon Route 53 Private Hosted Zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html).

> A private hosted zone is a container that holds information about how
>   you want to route traffic for a domain and its subdomains *within one
>   or more* Amazon Virtual Private Clouds (Amazon VPCs).

In this way, a Private Hosted Zone can be setup between the Legacy and NewGen VPCs.  A resource record in the private zone of `comp.com` can be associated to both VPCs.  A DNS query in each VPC for a resource will return the RR associated in the zone.